# How to auto-calculate without a need to drag down the formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

How can I fix formula to a row so that when data is inputted in any cell within that column, it auto-computed in Google Sheets? the % doesn't work

Without having to drag the formula down.

Example:

Column H contains data calculated from column B + E

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aV30tG5YkluaFgaYUHh6Gvbnsn1M2SIghyFzD063bss/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to calculate Overtime Rate by multiplying Hourly Rate by 1.5 (found in the Employees Sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B&E2:E), B2:B+E2:E, ))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]